# Getting total mysql results returned from query with a limit: FOUND_ROWS error

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, limit

I have this mysql query:

```
SELECT Files.GUID, Files.Name, Files.Type, Files.Visibility, Files.CreationDate, Files.OwnerUser, Date, BackupsCount
FROM Files
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT FileGUID, Date, COUNT(*) AS BackupsCount
    FROM Versions
    GROUP BY FileGUID
  ) Versions ON Files.GUID = Versions.FileGUID
WHERE Files.ParentFolder = '96251A8B-B2A8-416B-92D7-3509E6A645C7'
ORDER BY Files.Type DESC, CreationDate ASC
LIMIT 0, 50
```

I'd like to know how many record this query would return **if the LIMIT directive was not there**, I googled and found that I needed to add `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and `SELECT FOUND_ROWS();`

**MY problem is:** I couldn't get it to work:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM (
SELECT Files.GUID, Files.Name, Files.Type, Files.Visibility, Files.CreationDate, Files.OwnerUser, Date, BackupsCount
FROM Files
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT FileGUID, Date, COUNT(*) AS BackupsCount
    FROM Versions
    GROUP BY FileGUID
  ) Versions ON Files.GUID = Versions.FileGUID
WHERE Files.ParentFolder = '96251A8B-B2A8-416B-92D7-3509E6A645C7'
ORDER BY Files.Type DESC, CreationDate ASC
LIMIT 0, 50)

-- Find total rows
SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
```

Assuming this is good idea (I mean doing one query vs two separate ones), **how can I get the `FOUND_ROWS()` to work with this query?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is correct, and the second query is almost instantaneous. But you have to add the keyword after the `SELECT`, no more:

```
SELECT Files.GUID, Files.Name, Files.Type, ...
```

becomes

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS Files.GUID, Files.Name, Files.Type, ...
```

Then the number of found rows will be populated and you'll be able to recover it.

If you want to run a single **retrieval** query, but you are able to **execute** more than one query, then you can do this (it is two queries):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @FOUNDROWS FROM ( YOUR_QUERY_WITHOUT_SELECT ) AS orig;
```

and alter your retrieval query by adding `@FOUNDROWS as foundrows` to the fields:

```
SELECT ...YOUR FIELDS..., @FOUNDROWS AS foundrows FROM...
```

Finally you can run a JOIN as a single query containing the two queries:

```
SELECT ALL_YOUR_FIELDS, counter.FOUND_ROW_NUMBER FROM
( YOUR_QUERY_WITH_LIMIT ) AS limited
JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS FOUND_ROW_NUMBER FROM YOUR_QUERY ) AS counter;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still need both the rows **and** the total count. I mean adding `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` didn't show the total count when I run it

Comment: No, it wouldn't; it only **stores** the count, then you have to retrieve it in a second query. You could do it in a single query but it would cost you... I'll try and improve my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The query should be like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS Files.GUID, Files.Name, Files.Type, Files.Visibility, Files.CreationDate, Files.OwnerUser, Date, BackupsCount
FROM Files
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT FileGUID, Date, COUNT(*) AS BackupsCount
    FROM Versions
    GROUP BY FileGUID
  ) Versions ON Files.GUID = Versions.FileGUID
WHERE Files.ParentFolder = '96251A8B-B2A8-416B-92D7-3509E6A645C7'
ORDER BY Files.Type DESC, CreationDate ASC
LIMIT 0, 50
```

Comment: Thanks, but the query still only returns the rows, while I need both the rows **and** the total count

Comment: You get the count by doing: SELECT FOUND_ROWS() right after the first query

Answer (score 0):

```
A very simple example


 "SELECT SUM(final_cost) as final_cost,
SUM(call_discount) as discount_cost,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM call_records WHERE transaction_type ='call' AND account_id='$account_id' AND time_of_call>='$from' AND time_of_call<='$to' ) as calls,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM call_records WHERE transaction_type ='text' AND account_id='$account_id' AND time_of_call>='$from' AND time_of_call<='$to' ) as texts,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM call_records WHERE transaction_type ='appointment' AND account_id='$account_id' AND time_of_call>='$from' AND time_of_call<='$to' ) as appts
 FROM
 call_records
 WHERE account_id='$account_id'
 AND time_of_call>='$from'
 AND time_of_call<='$to' "
```